# How to determine the order of an element in a cartesian product group

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

because I've lost all confidence in my ability to math.
what is $o(([15],[12])) \in \Bbb Z_{18} \times \Bbb Z_{27}$
$o([15]) \in \Bbb Z_{18} = 6 $
$o([12]) \in \Bbb Z_{27} = 9 $
$o(([15],[12])) \in \Bbb Z_{18} \times \Bbb Z_{27} = n ;\ s.t. \ n = lcm( 6,9)= 18$
since n is minimum  $[15]^n =[0] \ \& \ [12]^n =[0]$

Comment: $o([15]) = 5$ is incorrect.

Comment: at least my confidence wasn't lost without cause. thanks.

Comment: Um, the lcm of 6 and 9 is 18. The *product* is 54.

Comment: thanks, brain must be really fried.